# Angularjs $http for external image call

Tags: angularjs, http, factory

I have set up a Plunker as I am trying to retrieve an external image via an $http call and return the URL on successful retrieval or status 200 and have a placeholder 'Image not available' if 404 or an error

http://plnkr.co/edit/ythKksFLWYA30laMGF1g?p=preview

```
angular.module('testApp')
  .factory('ProductImageFactory', function(config, $q, $http, $log) {
    return {
      getProductImg: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.jsonp(config.LINK)
          .success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve({
             console.log('return LINK');
            });
          }).error(function() {
            deferred.reject();
            console.log('Placeholder: Image not available')
          });
          return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: What's the issue you are getting?

Comment: Hi Reena, I am not getting anything at the moment, if you check the PLUNKER, I feel I might be missing something obvious

Comment: return(url) from where is this url u r passing as parameter????

Comment: Good spot that is not meant to be there. I just want to return the LINK

Comment: <img ng-src="{{productImg()}}" class="product-img">... I can't find this function productImg(), is it a function that you really want to use here?

Comment: TBH I would be open to improvements, anything to make it work. I'm not bound to this structure.

Answer (score -1):

So i tried to figure this out check my changed plunger out.
 click on the link

```
plunker
```

[click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/i2XaiEWhSAEzZywuW1Go?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, thank you. I'm not sure this is the direction I am going down, but thanks for taking the time!